# Adding a DataFrame to a level in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a MultiIndex DataFrame and would like to take a level and put a new DataFrame in its place. So if I had a DataFrame with levels like this:

```
a 1 
  2
b 3
  4
```

Would I be able to swap out ['b', 3] with a DataFrame like this

```
10
11
```

Resulting in this:

```
a 1
  2
b 10
  11
  4
```

Comment: Interesting question... are your values (e.g., `1, 2, 3, 4`) an index, or values in the df? Specifically, are you trying to replace some values, or replace parts of the index?

Comment: those are my indexes, I want to replace the whole row of data with multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

I took a crack at this, and couldn't quite get what you wanted. Instead of 'inserting' a df, you can delete the row(s) in question, then concat/join/merge as needed. However, this does not sort the data in the method you requested.

```
import pandas as pd

arrays = [['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], [1, 2, 3, 4], ['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*arrays)),
                   columns = ['let', 'num', 'string']).set_index(['let', 'num'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*[['b', 'b'], [10, 11], ['str5', 'str6']])),
                   columns = ['let', 'num', 'string']).set_index(['let', 'num'])

df3 = pd.concat([df1.drop(3, level = 'num'), df2])
```

Output:

```
        string
let num       
a   1     str1
    2     str2
b   4     str4
    10    str5
    11    str6
```

I tried a number of other methods to insert data into the middle of the df, and was met with error after error. I'll keep messing with it; it's a good problem-oriented multiindex tutorial.